# how can i use windows delete file / folder through c# code?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I want to delete a file or / folder via windows delete dialog.

i tried finding it everywhere online but couldn't.
how can i delete a file from c# code while using windows delete dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add

```
"Microsoft.VisualBasic"
```

in references of your project.

add using of:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
```

use:
for file:

```
FileSystem.DeleteFile(fullPath, UIOption.AllDialogs, RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin);
```

for directory:

```
FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(fullPath, UIOption.AllDialogs, RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin);
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.deletefile(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.deletefile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: anybody knows how to do it for a list of files? (not for one path but for multiple paths)?